# Maven OSB (12.2.1.3) issues

Tags: oracle, maven, plugins, repository, osb

I am trying to configure maven for deploying OSB projects. I ran the following 2 commands and both showed success:

> 1. mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.2.1.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.2.1.jar
> 2. mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DoracleHome=ORACLE_HOME

But as per Oracle doc https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/service-bus/12.2.1.3/develop/using-oracle-service-bus-development-maven-plug1.html#GUID-05C3C827-C474-4D27-9D35-7B82E2D6E080 when I am trying to run

> mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.servicebus.plugin
>   -DartifactId=oracle-servicebus-plugin -Dversion=12.2.1-0-0

to verify whether I have successfully installed the plug-in , I am getting the following errors:

1.

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error
>   retrieving plugin descriptor for:
>
> groupId: 'com.oracle.servicebus.plugin' artifactId:
>   'oracle-servicebus-plugin' version: '12.2.1-0-0'

2.

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin
>   com.oracle.servicebus.plugin:oracle-servicebus-plugin:12.2.1-0-0 or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
>   com.oracle.servicebus.plugin:oracle-servicebus-plugin:jar:12.2.1-0-0
>   in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: I suppose you are using the wrong groupId/artifactId for the plugin. check the pom file you are installing in your first step...

Comment: I checked the POM file and You are right.........But why in the Oracle docs they are then asking to run the command **mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.servicebus.plugin -DartifactId=oracle-servicebus-plugin -Dversion=12.2.1-0-0** after the second command?